# Connecting polypropylene to straight pipe (without inside bevel)

Tags: plumbing, drain

I have a couple of connections that seem like they *could* work but due to lack of the inside bevel I'm questioning whether or not this will be a good idea.

In both cases the threads match and the rubber gasket/washer snugs up nicely creating what feels like a good fit. However, the inside of the straight pipe *does not* have any inside bevel, whereas normally that gasket joins with pipe that has a angle inside so that it really connects.

Are either of these things acceptable?

#### Polypropylene to copper drain with male thread:

[image: Polypropylene to copper drain with male thread]

#### Polypropylene to Oatey Sure-Vent:

[image: Polypropylene to Oatey Sure-Vent]

Comment: Haven't seen these fittings, but I assume you checked that the bevel is not on the inside of the compression nut?  Your vent photo doesn't show a clear bevel.

Comment: I would guess the intended compression could deform the seal in an unfavorable way.

Comment: Your second comment is more my concern.  Neither the vent nor the copper have any bevel.  There is actually already a sink in this house that has this exact connection and *appears* to be doing ok.  Based on that I assume it can work, but I'm still looking for some kind of verification that this isn't a terrible idea.  The good news is, both of these connections will be under a utility sink and therefore visible in case of issues.

Answer (score 2):

> Polypropylene to copper drain with male thread

You should use a rubber 1 1/2" slip-joint gasket for this connection.

[image]

> Polypropylene to Oatey Sure-Vent

What you have should work fine, as long as the tapered edge of the slip-joint washer fits into the ID of the fitting (as opposed to butting up against it...)

Comment: Can you post an image or link to the 1 1/2" slip-joint gasket you mentioned? I thought that's exactly what I have on the end of that plastic pipe..?

Comment: And yes, in neither case does the washer butt up against the adjoining pipe.

Comment: I posted an image of a square-cut rubber slip-joint washer. The plastic one you have now may work if it fits into the ID of the male copper fitting (which will allow the *squeeze* needed when you tighten it up, otherwise use rubber there. NOTE - there is a common misconception that hand-tightening slip-joint drain fittings is sufficient; this is incorrect, they need to be cinched up with a wrench.